# Get ethernet router MAC address in android

Tags: android, ethernet, mac-address

I use this function to get device MAC address

```
public static String getMacAddress(){
        try {
            return loadFileAsString("/sys/class/net/eth0/address")
                    .toUpperCase().substring(0, 17);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now I need to also get mac address of router this ethernet is connected to. How can I do that?

Comment: I contributing an answer to your problem on this link.!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789324/5330408

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getBSSID()` of WifiInfo class will return the MAC address of remote access point.

According to [google docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getBSSID%28%29) it returns the basic service set identifier (BSSID) of the current access point in a form of mac address. The BSSID may be null if there is no network currently connected.

See here an example:

```
public String getMacId() {

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    return wifiInfo.getBSSID();
}
```

Comment: that probably works when device is connected through wifi, but it returns empty string when I try it on ethernet.